# Comparing 2 models of truth trees

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose I have the following truth tree:

[image]

I understand how it works. I also have the following tree (assume p = p_1 and q = p_2):

[image]

I got it from [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(%C2%ACq%E2%86%92%C2%ACp)%E2%86%92(p%E2%86%92q)). I've seen truth trees represented like this in other examples and couldn't understand them. Why are both branches closed?

Can someone explain to me how the 2nd model is equivalent to the 1st one? I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: Every branch closes because each branch contains a contradiction: $q, \lnot q$ for the left one and $p,\lnot p$ for the right one.

Comment: If every branch closes the root formula is unsatisfiable.

Comment: You can see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627553/what-do-the-paths-of-a-truth-tree-represent) for the basic definitions as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146059/prove-that-if-the-truth-tree-method-proves-a-sentence-a-from-a-set-of-sentence)

Comment: The procedure tests for *satisfiability*; you have checked formula $A$ and found open branches: thus, the formula is satisfiable. The second picture test formula $\lnot A$ and found it *unsatisfiable*; this means that $A$ is a *tautology*. The teo cases are not the same but they are consistent: if $A$ is taut, then it is sat.